# Rails click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

What I am trying to accomplish is that the user can select one of the items in the list group and ill be able to get returned which one it is along with making the item active in the group. I can't seem to get it working with jquery, or I am not doing this correctly.

Any feedback/help is appreciated.

Here is the HAML Code

```
= form_for @editor do |f|
  %body
   .container
    .list-group
      %a.list-group-item.active Hello 
      %a.list-group-item Hey 
      %a.list-group-item Greetings
```

I made a js file called editors.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".list-group-item").live('click', function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".list-group-item", function(){
  $(this).addClass('active')
    .siblings('.active')
    .removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item active">Hello</a>
  <a class="list-group-item">Hey</a>
  <a class="list-group-item">Greetings</a>
</div>
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item active">Bye</a>
  <a class="list-group-item">Adios</a>
  <a class="list-group-item">Auf Wiedersehen</a>
</div>
```

This also makes it idempotent and turbolinks compatible by delegating from the document instead of attaching the handler to a DOM node.

Comment: This still didn't change the result as it is not working on the app. What else could be going wrong?

Comment: The above code does work as intended so the error is somewhere else. But you need to actually debug it yourself by using the console in the browser.

Comment: You should also check that your javascript file is actually being included in application.js and is run by the browser.

Comment: Yea I have it included in my application.js file as required, but it is still not working. How do I properly debug for this issue?

Comment: I have been using the console. It doesn't seem like its getting loaded in, how do I fix this even though I am requiring the tree in the app.js

Comment: I just added the javascript code as a snippet in the browser and its working fine, but why doesn't rails let it work..?

Comment: How am I supposed to know? It could be anything from a syntax error to bad markup. If you want debugging help you need to create a verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am using turbo links in my project would this be a reason why its not working?